# CALayers() having wrong positions while adding stickers/images in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

**Here Im having one function in which I'm passing the AVAsset and UIImage that I want to add in the video ,code is working but I want my image to be on left most position as I start it with co ordinates (x : 0 ,y : 0) currently for co ordinates (x : 0 ,y : 0) it is staying at bottom left position.**

```
func mergeStickerToVideo(
  videoUrlAsset: AVAsset,
   withForegroundImage foregroundImage: UIImage) {
```

//       let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
//       let videoUrlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl, options: nil)

```
   // Setup `mutableComposition` from the existing video
   let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
   let videoAssetTrack = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
   let videoCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
   videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
   try! videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start:CMTime.zero, duration:videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: CMTime.zero)

let audioTracks = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)

let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

for audioTrack in audioTracks {
    try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
}
   let videoSize: CGSize = (videoCompositionTrack?.naturalSize)!
let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoSize)
   let imageLayer = CALayer()
   imageLayer.contents = foregroundImage.cgImage
   imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:350, height:350)
   let videoLayer = CALayer()
   videoLayer.frame = frame
   let animationLayer = CALayer()
   animationLayer.frame = frame
   animationLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
   animationLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)


   let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: (videoCompositionTrack?.asset!)!)
   videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: animationLayer)

   let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!
   let documentDirectoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
   let destinationFilePath = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("result.mp4")

   do {

       if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationFilePath.path) {

           try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationFilePath)

           print("removed")
       }



   } catch {

       print(error)
   }


   let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession( asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!

  exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
   exportSession.outputURL = destinationFilePath
   exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
   exportSession.exportAsynchronously { [weak exportSession] in
    if exportSession != nil {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: destinationFilePath)
                 }) { saved, error in
                     if saved {
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                         alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                     }
                 }
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: In Core Graphics layer coordinates, 0,0 is the bottom left.

Comment: So @matt can I change my stickers position to start from top left for 0,0 but my main video should not get flipped ?

Comment: I don't know what "my stickers" means.

Comment: imageLayer.contents = foregroundImage.cgImage

Comment: Ah. So does this help? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410872-contentsgravity

Comment: No results @matt

Comment: solved with animationLayer.isGeometryFlipped = true